# XNamespace + XName : The type 'XName' is not compatible with the type 'string'

Tags: .net, f#, linq-to-xml, xname

I am learning F# and I trying to write a simple XML parser. In C#, I can easily use the + operator to combine a namespace and name, but not in F#. I am getting the following error on the last line of the code below:

```
Error   1   Type constraint mismatch. The type 
    XName    
is not compatible with type
    string    
The type 'XName' is not compatible with the type 'string'
```

This is the code. The compiler doesn't like the "ns + d".

```
let parse(pageResult: DownloadPageResult) =
    if pageResult.ErrorOccured then 0
    else 
        let reader = new StringReader(pageResult.Source)
        let doc = XDocument.Load(reader)
        let ns = XNamespace.Get("a")
        let d = XName.Get("entry")
        doc.Elements(ns + d) |> Seq.length
```

Any idea why I am seeing this? Thanks!

Comment: Aside, if you're parsing some XML file with fairly static structure (and you have a good sample input), then you can try using the XML type provider from F# Data: http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/XmlProvider.html Might make your life a bit easier!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [XNamespace.Addition operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnamespace.op_addition.aspx) takes an `XNamespace` and a `string`. The compiler is complaining because you're attempting to pass an `XName`-typed variable (`d`) where it expects a `string`.

It should work if you change your last line to:

```
doc.Elements(ns + d.LocalName) |> Seq.length
```

Or, as Tomas points out, you don't even need to create the `d` variable, you can just use the name directly, like this:

```
doc.Elements(ns + "entry") |> Seq.length
```

Comment: +1 BTW: In this case, you can probably just write `ns + "entry"` because the `XName` value `d` is constructed on the line before (for no obvious reason...)

Comment: @TomasPetricek You're absolutely correct -- I've added that to my answer.